# PHP MySQL query error when passing a string

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am having an issue with a MySQL query not passing a string variable.

If `$pass` contains only numbers it works fine.
When it contains letters I get the `Cannot execute the query` error.

Example:

```
$pass=123456     //works fine
$pass=z23456     //cannot execute the query
$_SESSION['id']=$pass;           //start session

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

// Query database for user information.
$query = "SELECT RepName FROM RepTable WHERE RepNumber = 
".$_SESSION['id']."";
$result = mysql_query ($query) OR die ('Cannot execute the query.');
$rinfo = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
$RepInfo = $rinfo[0];
```

Comment: What type is RepNumber in the database?

Comment: A debugging tip:  try `OR die ("Cannot execute the query $query");` - use in development only - NEVER use it in production.  This will show you that, if for example `$pass`=`"foo"` your SQL statement reads `SELECT RepName FROM RepTable WHERE RepNumber = foo` - as you can see, `foo` is not a valid identifier, function or number, so will need to be quoted.  Assuming that RepNumber is a string type, mgraph's answer is your solution.  If RepNumber is a numeric type, then you will need to validate $pass first.

Comment: Incidentally, use of the mysql extension is discouraged; you really ought to consider using the mysqli or pdo extensions instead. [See here for more information](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
'".$_SESSION['id']."'"
```

instead of :

```
".$_SESSION['id'].""
```

you can also add:

```
mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared statements with mysql, it's safer (SQL injections for example) :

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Eg:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT RepName FROM RepTable WHERE RepNumber = ?");
$stmt->execute($_SESSION['id'])
```